# cache api response for offline use in ionic app

Tags: sqlite, caching, ionic-framework, offline-caching

I wanted to `cache` for all API calls, so that app can run while there is no internet. Below are some options i have came across

**SQLite**

I was thinking about this structure for table

```
--caches
id : auto incement
url : varchar:unique
body : text
expires_at : timestamp
created_at : timestamp
```

What you think about this table structure ?

I heard that iOS (app store) is not going to accept this app, since `SQLite db` wont backup to iCloud? whats the work around to this?

**localStorage**

or it will be enough to use `localStorage` for API response caching, But there is limit of `3-5mb` for localStorage, that can cause issue, for example. If I have 20 endpoints and all data will be cached, then it will surely cross this limit. and upon updates sometime `localStorage get cleared`.

Please help what will be prefer way to do this, since I wanted ionic app at least can access all the content which is present in cache.

There are some other options like `PouchDB` and others which uses browsers IndexDB but in iOS its not well supported.

I will be publishing this app for `iOS` and `Android`